# Bind after performing task?

Tags: jquery, onclick, delay, bind

The `delay()` doesn't seem to do the thing. After the user clicks a `.tab`, it should be disabled to click any other `.tab`, and after the stuff finishes, clicks should be enabled again.

```
$('.tab').on('click', function() {
    //disable user clicks while performing the stuff below
    $('.tab').unbind();
    //stuff going on here
    //enable clicking again
    $('.tab').delay( 500 ).bind();     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs says:

> **The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—`.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.**

`delay` is supposed to delay execution of items in jQuerys `fx` queue which is related to animations and effects.

For other purpose, you should use `setTimeout`. And since you're already using `on`, you should use `off` and stick with `on` rather than mixing it with `bind`.

```js
$('.tab').on('click', function handler() {
  //----------------------------^ for re-use
  //disable user clicks while performing the stuff below
  $('.tab').off();
  //stuff going on here
  //enable clicking again
  console.log('test');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.tab').on('click', handler);
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$('.tab').unbind();` you are **removes all handlers attached to the elements** not disable the event.

And `bind` need to given new event handlers. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tab').css("pointer-events", "none");
```

and

```
$('.tab').css("pointer-events", "auto");
```

instead of binds

Comment: This has browser support issues and not very reliable compared to built in jQuery methods to handle events.